# Detecting presence of NET Framework on client's PC via .aspx

Tags: asp.net, frameworks, client-side

is there any way of checking with an ASP.NET webpage 
if the client pc has the NET framework 2.0 installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

string version = [Request.Browser.ClrVersion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilities.clrversion.aspx).ToString();

This I think will reveal the clr version.  If this is not enough, you would need an object  downloaded to the client to investigate the clients computer.

Comment: This works fine in IE and FireFox, but Google Chrome returns 0.0.  I haven't got access to other browsers here to test.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Server Variables located in the HttpRequest object to check to see if the framework is installed. The frame work version is in the HTTP_USER_AGENT and would look something like this:

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)

Comment: Most of the time that only works in IE, but MS is aggressively pushing a firefox extension that will add this information as well.